# Databinding inside frendly url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater, friendly-url

This is inside a repeater.

Databinding does not work inside the friendlyurl but works fine outside.
ProductName works but not ProductID.
Friendly url works fine if i hardcode the ProductID

```
<li><a href="<%: FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Product", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID")) %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName") %></a></li>
```

i get this error.

**The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context**

the Container word inside the friendlyurl is red underlined in visual studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change to (note the #), this should work...

```
<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Product", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID"))
```